# Tensorflow split or unstack to work with interleaved values

Tags: python, tensorflow

Say I have a Tensorflow tensor `l` with shape [20,] and these are 10 coordinates packed as `[x1,y1,x2,y2,...]`.  I need access to `[x1,x2,...]` and `[y1,y2,...]` to modify their values (*e.g.*, rotate, scale, shift) and then repackage as `[x1',y1',x1',y2',...]`.

I can [reshape](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reshape), `tf.reshape(l, (10, 2))`, but then I'm not sure whether to use [split](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/split) or [unstack](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/unstack) and what the arguments should be.  When should one use split instead of unstack? And then how should the modified values be repacked so they're in the original format?

Comment: I don't know tensorflow, only numpy, but looking at the docs I think `unstack` with `axis=1` should separate `x` and `y`, then you can `stack` them back together then `reshape` again, in reverse order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the kind of stuff that can be easily verifiable with tensorflow's eager execution mode:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

tf.enable_eager_execution()

l = np.arange(20)
y = tf.reshape(l, [10, 2])
a = tf.split(y, num_or_size_splits=2, axis=1)
b = tf.unstack(y, axis=1)

print('reshaped:', y, sep='\n', end='\n\n')

for operation, c in zip(('split', 'unstack'), (a, b)):
    print('%s:' % operation, c, sep='\n', end='\n\n')
```

```sh
reshaped:
tf.Tensor(
[[ 0  1]
 [ 2  3]
 ...
 [16 17]
 [18 19]], shape=(10, 2), dtype=int64)

split:
[<tf.Tensor: id=5, shape=(10, 1), dtype=int64, numpy=
array([[ 0],
       [ 2],
       ...
       [16],
       [18]])>,
 <tf.Tensor: id=6, shape=(10, 1), dtype=int64, numpy=
array([[ 1],
       [ 3],
       ...
       [17],
       [19]])>]

unstack:
[<tf.Tensor: id=7, shape=(10,), dtype=int64, numpy=array([ 0,  2, ... 16, 18])>,
 <tf.Tensor: id=8, shape=(10,), dtype=int64, numpy=array([ 1,  3, ... 17, 19])>]
```

**So they are pretty much the same, using these parameters**; except by:

- `tf.split` will always split the tensor along the `axis` into `num_or_size_splits` splits, which can potentially be different than the number of dimensions `shape[axis]` and therefore needs to retain the original rank, outputting tensors of shape `[10, n / num_or_size_splits] = [10, 2 / 2] = [10, 1]`.

  Repacking can be performed by concatenating all split parts in `a`:

  ```py
  c=tf.concat(a, axis=1)
  print(c)
  array([[ 0,  1],
         [ 2,  3],
         ...
         [16, 17],
         [18, 19]])>
  ```
- `tf.unstack` will split the tensor along the `axis` into the exact amount of dimensions `shape[axis]`, and can therefore unambiguously reduce the rank by `1`, resulting in tensors of shape `[10]`.

  Repacking can be performed by stacking all split parts in `b`:

  ```py
  c=tf.stack(b, axis=1)
  print(c)
  array([[ 0,  1],
         [ 2,  3],
         ...
         [16, 17],
         [18, 19]])>
  ```

Comment: Thanks, but while it's clear `stack` is the inverse of `unstack`, please be explicit in how to un-`split` to return to the original format.

Comment: Sorry, I was on eager answer mode. I've updated the answer with what you needed.